# Javascript imports in openlayers

Tags: javascript, html, import, openlayers

On the tiledWMS geoserver example available at openlayers.org, https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-tiled.html, there are imports within the script tag.

```
<script>
  import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
  import View from 'ol/View.js';
  import {Image as ImageLayer, Tile as TileLayer} from 'ol/layer.js';
  import ImageWMS from 'ol/source/ImageWMS.js';
  import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM.js';
 ...
</script>
```

However when running the exammple it produces the error.

*/home/user/tiledWMS/index.html:1:16: Imports and requires are not suported inside inline  tags yet.*

and directs to these imports, if the script is put in a seperate .js file it seems to be ignored.

Is this correct and has a mistake been made on my part? or is there a better way to provide these imports?

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/310482/unexpected-token-identifier-error-import-openlayers or https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/310467/import-from-in-openlayers (including comments)

Comment: Thank you. I had searched but had not come across these answers. I will try them immediately.